# What does (Theta1(:,2:end).^2,2) mean in this code?

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, octave, regularized

What does `(Theta2(:, 2:end).^2, 2)` mean?

```
p = sum(sum(Theta1(:, 2:end).^2, 2))+sum(sum(Theta2(:, 2:end).^2, 2));
```

Comment: Both the MATLAB and Octave tag guides say "Questions should be tagged with either [matlab] or [octave], but not both, unless the question explicitly involves both packages." This is the text that is shown when you select the tags to add to your question. Also, please read [ask].

Comment: The code excerpt in the OP title is a syntax error. The "2" before the closing bracket is the second argument to the [`sum()`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sum.html) function and indicates that the sum should be computed for every row of the matrix in the first argument. The first argument means: Take all rows of `Theta1` and all columns, beginning from the second, and square the elements individually.

Answer (score 0):

Let's start from the most inner parentheses. First, `Theta1(:, 2:end).^2` maintains all the columns of `Theta1` except the first one then squares it. Let denote the result with `mem1`. Then after, `sum(mem1,2)` computes the **column sum** whose output is the sum of all the columns of `mem1` and therefore is a column itself. (`sum(mem1,1)` or `sum(mem1)` computes the **row sum**). Then `sum(sum(mem1,2))` computes the summation of elements of `sum(mem1,2)` which finally yields to the sum of all elements of `Theta1` squared. The same is true for `Theta2`.

P.S. You can simply use `p = sum(sum(Theta1(:, 2:end).^2+Theta2(:, 2:end).^2));` as the result is the same

Answer (score 0):

Let's say we have a matrix theta2 of size (3,3) and we want to calculate the above expression that you've given which is sum(sum(Theta2(:, 2:end).^2, 2)).
First of all let's break the expression:

1. theta2(:,2:end).^2 --> choose all rows(which is shown by ':' instead of any row number) but choose the columns greater than equal to 2 and square each term.

2.sum(theta2(:,2:end).^2,2) --> sum the squares column wise.

3.sum(sum(theta2(:,2:end).^2,2)) --> Now, sum the resulting sum from the sum obtained by second step.